# How to make outdoor activities questions and answers more popular?

Tags: discussion

I have a german website about vacation rentals. Does anybody knows if it is allowed to link https://outdoors.stackexchange.com or other websites, without any permissions?

Comment: I don't think you _ever_ need permission to link to other websites.

Comment: This is probably more suitable for law.SE.  You never need permission to add a link, but you may need it to quote or embed data from another site within your own.

Comment: The title doesn't make sense and doesn't relate to the question asked in the body.

Comment: Can you give an example of the sort of thing you want to do? I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

If you see a question on this site that you think people who read your website could answer, by all means add a link to it there, along with a sentence like "Can you answer this?" or a short summary of the question. To get the link, use the Share link under the question, that way you may earn a badge like [Announcer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer).

If you see a question with one or more great answers, same thing, but use different text like "wondering how to X? These great question has some wonderful answers that explain how it's done." Again use the share link.

The fact that SE gives out badges for sharing these links is a sure sign they want you to do it.

What not to do: don't write an "article" on your site that is a copy and paste of an answer from here, or otherwise reuse text from this site on your site. Using the subject line of a question is fine, using the whole thing is not.

Comment: Actually, that last paragraph is somewhat inaccurate - since the content is licenced under a Creative Commons licence (linked from the footer of every page), you are permitted to copy and reuse the text as long as you abide by the conditions of that licence (principally, you must provide correct attribution, and allow further sharing).